# Reactive Forms, trigger three click events uniquely.1.To submit form 2.To send data from dropdown 3. Same as two, in same Reactive Form

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have written a Reactive form. The submit button is supposed to be outside the Reactive form.It has also got two dropdowns. In this form im reading data dynamically from api. I have written click events in the dropdown as well(for a purpose to bind that particular value when i submit the form). The issue here is that whenever i click on the dropdown...the submit button click event is getting triggered....i have been trying to make them(the three click events) be unique...but im unable to.... kindly help me. Below im providing my code.

```
    <div class="container content-box-shadow tiles-top-spacing tiles-page">
    <div class="row assessment-m-b">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 pt-3 pb-5">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <span class="common-headding">{{pageText?.accountSettingPageTextData?.editHeader}}</span>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="common-button green"
                        (click)="onSubmit()">{{pageText?.accountSettingPageTextData?.save}}</button>
                    <button type="button"
                        class="common-button orange" (click)="previousModule()">{{pageText?.accountSettingPageTextData?.cancel}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="account-settings-block">
                <form *ngIf="personalData" [formGroup]="accountSettingsForm" >..................................................

                    <!-- Account-Settings Security Questions -->
                    <div *ngIf=" personalData?.dashBoardPersonalInfoData?.securityQuestionsAnswers.isVisible"
                        class="account-form-inner-block">
                        <legend>{{pageText?.accountSettingPageTextData?.questions?.header}}<span class="required">**</span></legend>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="question1">
                                        {{pageText?.accountSettingPageTextData?.questions?.question1}}
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="btn-group w-100 pt-1" ngbDropdown>

                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle w-100 text-left"
                                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenu1"
                                            ngbDropdownToggle>
                                            <span *ngIf="!SecurityQuestion1.question">
                                                Select a Question
                                            </span>
                                            <span *ngIf="SecurityQuestion1.question">
                                                {{SecurityQuestion1.question}}
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                            <button (click)="selectQuestion1(questions)"
                                                *ngFor="let questions of personalData?.dashBoardPersonalInfoData?.securityQuestions"
                                                class="dropdown-item">{{questions?.question}}
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="question2">
                                        {{pageText?.accountSettingPageTextData?.questions?.question2}}
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="btn-group w-100 pt-1" ngbDropdown>
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle w-100 text-left"
                                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenu2"
                                            ngbDropdownToggle>
                                            <span *ngIf="!SecurityQuestion2.question">
                                                Select a Question
                                            </span>
                                            <span *ngIf="SecurityQuestion2.question">
                                                {{SecurityQuestion2.question}}
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                            <button (click)="selectQuestion2(questions)"
                                                *ngFor="let questions of personalData?.dashBoardPersonalInfoData?.securityQuestions"
                                                class="dropdown-item">{{questions?.question}}
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my issue above by using form="myForm" attribute in the save button. and using id="myForm" attribute in the form tag.....just by using those attributes....i could have unique trigger for all the three events......Im stilll keeping posted so that someone neednot have to waste almost 4hours or more in finding it out....